# Method invocation failed because [Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mangement.ADGroup] doesn't contain a method named 'substring'

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I am stumped. I have what I thought should work in a script to pull all groups and get the users in those groups from AD.

```ps
    $ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select Name | Sort Name
    ForEach($Group in $ADGroupList)
    {
        $GroupName = $Group.substring($Group.length -7, $Group.length -8)
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$GroupName" | Select Name, SAMAccountName | Sort Name
        ForEach($member in $members)
        {
            Write-Host ($member.Name + "," + $member.SAMAccountName  + "," + $Group.name)
        }
    }
```

It keeps failing with the following error:

> Method invocation failed because [Selected.Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Mangement.ADGroup] doesn't contain a method named 'substring'

Where did I go wrong? I thought `SubString` was a PowerShell method?

Comment: [`Substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Substring) is a method of the .NET [`System.String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String) type (`[string]` in PowerShell), which is _available_ in PowerShell, but is not a PowerShell feature itself. You can only call it on `[string]`-typed values, which your `$Group` variable is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking to get substring of the Name of the object. Change your group statement to this,

```
$GroupName = $Group.Name.substring($Group.Name.length -7, $Group.Name.Length -8)
             #    string.substring(startIndex           , number of characters)
```

**Note**
Powershell's substring method takes in the index and number of characters you need from that index. the method .substring does not have start and end as one might think.

*Documentation:*

```
Substring()
Return part of a longer string.

Syntax
      .Substring( StartIndex [, length] )


Key
   StartIndex  Characters to skip from the start of the string.
               Use 0 to start from the beginning of the string.
               Cannot be less than zero.

   length      The number of characters to return.
               Cannot be less than zero or longer than the string.
               If omitted all remaining characters will be returned.
```

Comment: @Mike made a little bit of a change... .substring takes one or two arguments. 2 arguments require first to be the index and second argument to say how many you need.

Comment: right, I did know that. That's why I ended up just using `$Group.Name.substring(7)` as that will begin at the 7th character and continue to the end. It did work for me, though others may have to tweak it to suit their needs. I do appreciate the additional info!

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone stumbles on this in the future here is the end result including the out put to a csv:

```
    $ADGroupList = Get-ADGroup -Filter * | Select Name | Sort Name
    "Group,UserName,Name" | Out-File -FilePath OutputUserGroups.csv -Append -Encoding ASCII
    ForEach($Group in $ADGroupList)
    {
        $GroupName = $Group.Name.substring(7)
        $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity "$GroupName" | Select Name, SAMAccountName | Sort Name   
        ForEach($member in $members)
        {
            ($Group.name + "," + $member.SAMAccountName + "," + $member.Name) | Out-File -FilePath OutputUserGroups.csv -Append -Encoding ASCII
        }
    }
```